# joomla 2.5. doesn't show registration form validation messages

Tags: php, joomla2.5, user-registration

Using Joomla 2.5, I have menu item that points to User Manager Registration Form (without language and other staff), it shows just basic fields - username, email, password. If I enter two emails that are not equal, then validation happens and form doesn't allow user to go to the nexst step (doesn't send activation email), however, it doesn't show any error messages.

I am new to Jooma. It is very strange, but I have not found anything useful about this topic in google search. I also tried to find some place where I can configure registration form, but without success. 
I am using default user registration template (I have just changed submit button class).

1) Can you, please, point me to some usefull links or give other clues how to show validation error messages on user registration form.

2) When user is registered successfully, it simply loads an empty pages? Is it default behavior or I have made something with this? **EDIT:** I have found out that default layout after use registration is empty indeed. I will change it per my needs, and this part of question is solved.

Comment: What are you using for the template?

Comment: I have my custom template, but for registration I use default one.

Comment: Does your custom template include `<jdoc:include type="message" />`? Without that the system will queue messages but won't actually display them: http://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to include    `<jdoc:include type="message" />` just above your     `<jdoc:include type="component" />`in index.php file of your template (as Davis sad).

Maybe you have also set some css code (.error) in your style template folder that accidentally hide your messages.

Comment: Is there a way to include this message into component and not outside it?

Comment: Another thing is that this works for login form, but for registration form just partly. It seems that default registration form has some client side validation and it doesn't appear any messages in this case.

Comment: I have a new idea... Do you use any other languages on your site? It may happen that in your language file their is no value for this messages... If you just want to include just login messages in component try it with some javascript (hide and append html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the javascript in joomla, it just blocks the submission of the form without displaying any helpfull messages god knows why :).
It even blocks the browser messages try to disable js and you will see them ;)
The most easy solution is simply removing: JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
from the view in an override and let the user see the serverside validation.

Btw it does give an attribute "aria-invalid=true" which you can style, but it does not have any error messages but does make sure the content is filled in and email matches.